# Ruby newb requesting assistance with basic classes

Tags: ruby

I am trying to figure out why my code below is not working.  As you can see, the code is very brief and simple.

Could someone please help me understand why I am receiving this error message:

> > "NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass"

when I enter this command into terminal (after loading script):

> > mex_cuisine.add_recipe("charro beans")

The script:

```
class Cookbook

    attr_accessor :title, :recipes, :recipe
    def initialize(title)
        @title = title
        @recipes = []
    end

    def add_recipe(recipe)
        @recipe = recipe
        @recipes << @recipe
    end
end

class Recipe

    attr_accessor :name, :ingredients, :steps
    def initialize(name, ingredients, steps)
        @name = name
        @ingredients = ingredients
        @steps = steps
    end

end
```

Your assistance is much appreciated.
Thank you.

**Edit:

Substituting this code:

```
def add_recipe(recipe)
    @recipes.push(recipe)
    puts "Added a recipe to the collection: #{recipe.title}"
end
```

causes the same error... Here is the long version:

> > NoMethodError: undefined method `push' for nil:NilClass
> >      from cookbook.rb:10:in`add_recipe'
> >      from (irb):173
> >      from /Users/patrickmeaney/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/irb:11:in `'

**Edit:

Here is the given test code:

```
mex_cuisine = Cookbook.new("Mexican Cooking")
burrito = Recipe.new("Bean Burrito", ["tortilla", "bean"], ["heat beans", "place beans in tortilla", "roll up"])

mex_cuisine.recipes # []
mex_cuisine.add_recipe(burrito)
```

Comment: what exactly is mex_cuisine? could you please post the stacktrace of the error too?

Comment: The code you posted produces no errors.

Comment: Very weird.  It is working indeed.  I wonder what happened... I had been re-loading the script upon every edit.  Perhaps I failed to initialize the new classes properly, so that they were nil?  Sorry for this noob-ness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following code in a file called my_prog.rb:

```
class Cookbook

    attr_accessor :title, :recipes, :recipe
    def initialize(title)
        @title = title
        @recipes = []
    end

    def add_recipe(recipe)
        @recipe = recipe
        @recipes << @recipe
    end
end

class Recipe

    attr_accessor :name, :ingredients, :steps
    def initialize(name, ingredients, steps)
        @name = name
        @ingredients = ingredients
        @steps = steps
    end

end

class Cookbook

    attr_accessor :title, :recipes, :recipe
    def initialize(title)
        @title = title
        @recipes = []
    end

    def add_recipe(recipe)
        @recipe = recipe
        @recipes << @recipe
    end
end

class Recipe

    attr_accessor :name, :ingredients, :steps
    def initialize(name, ingredients, steps)
        @name = name
        @ingredients = ingredients
        @steps = steps
    end

end

mex_cuisine = Cookbook.new("Mexican Cooking")
burrito = Recipe.new("Bean Burrito", ["tortilla", "bean"], ["heat beans", "place beans in tortilla", "roll up"])

mex_cuisine.recipes # []
mex_cuisine.add_recipe(burrito)
```

Open a terminal window and cd to the same directory as my_prog.rb.  Then run your program:

```
ruby my_prog.rb
```

There will be no errors.

Comment: I think the problem was just failing to re-initialize classes (in the terminal-- i had been inputting all test code through terminal) after editing the Cookbook class (just my suspicion)

Comment: By 'terminal' do you mean irb?  If so, I think you will find it much easier to use practice files with names a.rb, b.rb, c.rb instead of trying things in irb.  irb is a pain.

Comment: Yes, I was using IRB.  The tutorial I am using just suggested to use a sort of "test_code.rb" file, similar to what you suggest.  Thanks for your helpful recommendation.